How to make a game's executable use your GPU instead of CPU on Kubuntu/KDE Plasma?
I only have one GPU: a Radeon RX 7900 XTX. This is what "xrandr --listproviders" has to say about my system: https://i.imgur.com/CtZa19U.png
For example, let's say I want to run the game "mari0" with my GPU. If you go to "edit application" in the Launcher, you'll see windows like this: https://i.imgur.com/F44FnKZ.png
I read that in my case I'd probably need to add "DRI_PRIME=1" or "env DRI_PRIME=1" somewhere. I just don't know where, though. Is it on "Arguments" or "Terminal options"?
Or do I actually need to do something entirely different?

This is an environment variable. I'm not 100% familiar with snaps but if it works like running anything else then usually you can just add it before the command you run. Like DRI_PRIME=1 mari0 instead of simply running the command mari0.
If you need to add the environment variable to a desktop launcher that you click on to run the game, then edit the mariO_mariO.desktop file manually using a text editor.
On the line for Exec=, it should say something like Exec=/snap/bin/mariO %u, for example. Based on this example, you would edit that line to say the following instead:
Exec=env DRI_PRIME=1 bash -c '/snap/bin/mariO %u'

Save the changes to the file and it should run that way when you click on the launcher.
